# Cypher query to stop graph traversal when reaching a hub

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database that contains highly connected nodes (hubs). These nodes can have more than 40000 relationships.

When I want to traverse the graph starting from a node, I would like to stop traversal at these hubs not to retrieve too many nodes.

I think I should use aggregation function and conditional stop based on the count of relationship for each node, but I didn't manage to write the good cypher query.

I tried:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r*..10]-(m)
WHERE n.name='MyNodeName' AND ALL (x IN nodes(p) WHERE count(x) < 10)
RETURN p;
```

and also:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*..10]-(m) WHERE n.name='MyNodeName' AND COUNT(r) < 10 RETURN p;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't stop the query at some node if you `MATCH` a path of length 10. You could count the number of relationships for all nodes in the path, but only *after* the path is matched.

You could solve this by adding an additional label to the hub nodes and filter that in your query:

```
MATCH (a:YourLabel)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]-()
WITH a, count(r) as count_rels
CASE
WHEN count_rels > 20000
THEN SET a :Hub
END
```

Your query:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r*..10]-(m)
WHERE n.name='MyNodeName' AND NONE (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x:Hub)
RETURN p
```

I used this approach in a similar case.

Answer (score 1):

Since Neo4j 2.2 there is a cool trick to use the internal `getDegree()` function to determine if a node is a dense node.

You also forgot the label (and probably index) for `n`

For your case that would mean:

```
MATCH p=(n:Label)-[r*..10]-(m)
WHERE n.name='MyNodeName'  AND size((m)--()) < 10
RETURN p;
```